# Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

I have class **LoadJSONTask**. In this class I am getting the error below.
My application is running but when I try to add progress bar in the code its not working.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu, PID: 3809
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu.LoadJSONTask$Listener.onLoaded(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
                  at in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu.LoadJSONTask$override.onPostExecute(LoadJSONTask.java:83)
                  at in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu.LoadJSONTask$override.access$dispatch(LoadJSONTask.java)
                  at in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu.LoadJSONTask.onPostExecute(LoadJSONTask.java:0)
                  at in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu.LoadJSONTask.onPostExecute(LoadJSONTask.java:21)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

**LoadJSONTask class**

```
package in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response>  {

private MainActivity activity;
private ProgressBar dwBar;

public LoadJSONTask(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
     dwBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
}

public LoadJSONTask(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface Listener {
    void onLoaded(List<AndroidVersion> androidList);
    void onError();
}

private Listener mListener;

@Override
protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {

        String stringResponse = loadJSON(strings[0]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.fromJson(stringResponse, Response.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();
    dwBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {

    dwBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (response != null) {

        mListener.onLoaded(response.getAndroid());//getting error here

    } else {

        mListener.onError();
    }



}

private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package in.kalakaaristudios.json.listviewmenu;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class LoadJSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response>  {

private MainActivity activity;
private ProgressBar dwBar;

public LoadJSONTask(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
     dwBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
}


public LoadJSONTask(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public interface Listener {
    void onLoaded(List<AndroidVersion> androidList);
    void onError();
}

private Listener mListener;

@Override
protected Response doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {

        String stringResponse = loadJSON(strings[0]);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return gson.fromJson(stringResponse, Response.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    MainActivity mn = new MainActivity();
    dwBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Response response) {

    dwBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (response != null) {

        mListener.onLoaded(response.getAndroid());

    } else {

        mListener.onError();
    }
}

private String loadJSON(String jsonURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(jsonURL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new        InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        response.append(line);
    }

    in.close();
    return response.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is on this line

```
dwBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

because you are using the activity class instance to obtain a reference to your ProgressBar View widget

You should inflate a layout that contains the ProgressBar widget and use the find to get an instance of your ProgressBar

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.Layout_that_contains_progress_bar, null);
dwBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
```

Alternatively, you can create ProgressBar programmatically like below

```
dwBar = new ProgressBar(activity);
```